# Python : want to return a 2D list that matches an pattern list

Tags: python, regex, list, pattern-matching

I have a 2D list of elements named `input_list` as shown below. It contains various nested lists with several list elements having text data.

```
input_list = [['UserName', 'EmailID', 'NoofLogins', 'Logs'],
              ['abariettq7g3sab9s2', 'abariett@polarstar.com', 1.0, 'User : Abariett has logged in successfully. $$'],
              ['adminadswdasdpj362xQ', 'admin@windacademy.us', 1.0, 'User : Admin has logged in successfully. $$ Scan Started Successfully for - Account Name : windacademy.us. $$'],
              ['adminadswdsaasdpjasxQ', 'archer@windacademy.us', 1.0, 'User : Admin has logged in successfully. $$ User kevin@gou.lo deleted $$'],
              ['abariettq7g3sab9s2', 'abariett@polarstar.com', 1.0, 'User : Abariett has logged out successfully. $$']
             ]
```

Here is the `valid_pattern` list i'm matching the `input_list` with,

```
valid_pattern = ['started', 'initiated', 'stopped', 'added', 'fetched', 'completed', 'deleted', 'updated', 'disabled']
```

from the 2-D `input_list`, I want only  the lists that match any item in the `valid_pattern` list, like the one shown below.

```
output_list = [['adminadswdasdpj362xQ', 'admin@windacademy.us', 1.0, 'User : Admin has logged in successfully. $$ Scan Started Successfully for - Account Name : windacademy.us. $$']
               ['adminadswdsaasdpjasxQ', 'archer@windacademy.us', 1.0, 'User : Admin has logged in successfully. $$ User kevin@gou.lo deleted $$']
              ]
```

See in `output_list`, the only 2 nested list that matched a pattern element **started** in the first case and **deleted** in the second case. 
How to get this output?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest also use a nested list comprehension:

```
[i for i in input_list if any(j in str(i).lower() for j in valid_pattern)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> pprint.pprint([i for i in input_list if any(j in str(i).lower() for j in valid_pattern)])
[['adminadswdasdpj362xQ',
  'admin@windacademy.us',
  1.0,
  'User : Admin has logged in successfully. $$ Scan Started Successfully for - '
  'Account Name : windacademy.us. $$'],
 ['adminadswdsaasdpjasxQ',
  'archer@windacademy.us',
  1.0,
  'User : Admin has logged in successfully. $$ User kevin@gou.lo deleted $$']]
```